# How to save settings in wordpress product page?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

[image]

I have try out following code:

```
      if(isset($_POST['save']))
            {
                   global $wpdb,$product;
                    $id = $product->id;

                    $custommsg = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['customstock-msg'] );
                    $customprocessingtime = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['customstock-Processing-time'] );
                    $customstockquantity = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['customstock-quantity'] );
                    $customstockcatlogpage = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['customstock-catlogpage'] );
                    $customstockinstockdate = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['customstock-instockdate'] );
                    $customstockinstockdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($customstockinstockdate) );

 $wpdb->insert('wp_woocommerce_specific_product_settings', array(
                                                                    'custom_msg' => $custommsg,
                                                                    'order_processing_time'  => $customprocessingtime,
                                                                    'exp_instock_date' => $customstockinstockdate, 
                                                                    'show_stockstatus_quantity' => $customstockquantity,
                                                                    'showon_catlog' => $customstockcatlogpage,
                                                                    'specific_product_id' =>  $id
                                                                ));
            }
```

I am beginner in wordpress can Anyone give solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use the woocommerce's action hook `woocommerce_process_product_meta`.

Following is the code that should go into your functions.php file. You might want to rename the custom meta fields as required. (in the `update_post_meta` statement).

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'wp_woo_save_product_custom_meta' );
function wp_woo_save_product_custom_meta( $post_id ){
    $custommsg = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['customstock-msg'] );
    if( !empty( $custommsg ) ){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'customstock_msg', $custommsg ) );
    }
    $customprocessingtime = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['customstock-Processing-time'] );
    if( !empty( $customprocessingtime ) ){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'customstock_Processing_time', $customprocessingtime ) );
    }
    $customstockquantity = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['customstock-quantity'] );
    if( !empty( $customstockquantity ) ){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'customstock_quantity', $customstockquantity ) );
    }
    $customstockcatlogpage = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['customstock-catlogpage'] );
    if( !empty( $customstockcatlogpage ) ){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'customstock_catlogpage', $customstockcatlogpage ) );
    }
    $customstockinstockdate = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['customstock-instockdate'] );
    $customstockinstockdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($customstockinstockdate) );
    if( !empty( $customstockinstockdate ) ){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'customstock_instockdate', $customstockinstockdate ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: If I want to store in another table then what should do?

Comment: Why do you want to store in another table? Reason I am asking is, its always better to save meta data in the wordpress' native way, so that it can be retrieved using wordpress/woocommerce native functions, which out too much of customization.

Comment: Then How I can can retrieve meta value after inserting in post meta I am beginners so  I don't have idea.

Comment: By using `get_post_meta`
Learn more about it here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Comment: I guess you are working on some e-Commerce portal with wordpress and woocommerce combination. I hope following 2 links will help you to learn more.
[**Wordpress Function References**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/)
AND [**WooCommer Action and Filter Hook Reference**](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html)

You will be able to find solution to most of your problems on above 2 links. Cheers, happy coding.

Comment: Yes,I am working on e-portal with wordpress and woocommerce combination.

Comment: Check the 2 links I have posted in previous comment. I am sure those links will help you. And if this answer has helped you, can you plz mark it as accepted?